# Push notification is not working in the build file but it works with xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I am working for push notification in iOS application. All is working fine when i run the application from xcode to real device and check the notification it works, but when i make the build file from diawi.com and install it on devices it does not work. Please tell me what is the problem and how can i solve it?

One more thing my application build setting shown as on given screen, is it problem for the push notification or other?

[image: build setting screen]

Comment: did you configure for push for production mode? i.e. create a production certificate in the ios dev center and uploaded it to your server?

Comment: Are you sure correct device id is used for sending push notification ? the device id is subject to change sometimes...My gut feeling is you are trying with the same device id that you found when using with xcode.

Comment: Looks like an issue during the build, maybe the build settings. Asking support team of the service that you are using to build the app seems like a better idea than asking us who mostly know nothing about this service and don't have an access to your specific project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this link step by step:-

https://parse.com/tutorials/push-notifications

And note that:-

While creating Production SSL certificate, do not change the name "aps_production.cer".

And before creating Development related certificates, first create certificates(SSL,provisioning,p12) for only production.

It really worked for me after trying different approaches.

Comment: https://parse.com/tutorials/push-notifications your link takes me to a place where a can't find anythind related to the issue. Please could you update it?

Answer (score 2):

It is issue with Setting up mobile Provisioning profile at Code Signing..

In your screen shot you are setting mobile provision with iPhone Development. Push notification needs distribution mobile provision..(iPhone Distribution)

So, May be that is the issue for you..Check it..

Answer (score 1):

I think you use mobile provision without enabled APNS server (I assume that you sign your application at diawi.com with another mobile provision (not that you use for debug). 
So please check mobile provision profile in application that builds with diawi.com. 
You can find it it application (rename your application bundle to rar file and unarchive it, than find mobile provision). After it find this provision in your program and check if APNS service enabled for this mobile provision.